# When will a data provider annotation will be executed in testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng, dataprovider

I am running a Testng xml in selenium. It has

```
@BeforeSuite
@BeforeTest
@Dataprovider
@Test(2 methods)
@AfterTest
@AfterSuite
```

When will the data provider method will be executed, at which phase. Will it execute before BeforeSuite or BeforeTest ? will it be executed fully ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `@Dataprovider(name="testdata")` from your `@test` annotation and not from other annotations like `@beforesuite` etc. You need to call the dataprovider from the `@test` annotation like `@Test(dataProvider="testdata")`

The `@dataprovider` will be executed whenever you call from your `@test` method

Comment: Suppose I have many variables and logic written in dataprovider. So I want to know how many the times dataprovider method will be invoked ? For each @Test annotation will it be invoked ?

Comment: It depends on your requirement and it won't be executed for each "@Test" annotation unless you call the Data Provider. It will be executed only if you call the "Data Provider" with its Name from your "@test" method. Please accept this answer if I have answered your question.